# How to do jButtongroup use to select radiobutton using java

Tags: java, swing

i am create simple rating system in java. we have 5 radio button for rating the course.i attached screen shot image below.i have group buttonGroup1,buttonGroup2,buttonGroup3

[image]

i have do code in below. what i tried so far. first i tried with buttonGroup1 but i got the error was method isSelected in class ButtonGroup cannot ne applied to given types
requird Button Model . how to write the code here properly and get it.

```
 if(buttonGroup1.isSelected())
        {
            
            if(r1.isSelected()){  
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"1");    
          }  
             else if(r2.isSelected()){  
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"2");    
          }  
             else if(r3.isSelected()){  
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"3");    
          }  
             else if(r4.isSelected()){  
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"4");    
          }  
            
             else if(r5.isSelected()){  
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"5");    
          }  
           
        }
```

**if(buttonGroup1.isSelected())**  this line go the error method isSelected in class ButtonGroup cannot ne applied to given types
requird Button Model .

Comment: you probably suppose to pass some value inside isSelected method

Comment: ya. i don't know what the value pass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonGroup.isSelected(ButtonModel m)` is not really what you want here, because this checks if a particular `ButtonModel` is selected. Either, you omit the whole outer if statement and just check all single radio buttons for selection, or you can use `getSelection()` and check for null.

Example:

```
if (buttonGroup1.getSelection() != null) {

    if (r1.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "1");
    } else if (r2.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "2");
    } else if (r3.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "3");
    } else if (r4.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "4");
    } else if (r5.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "5");
    }
}
```

Comment: if (buttonGroup1.getSelected() != null))  this line error displayed illegal start expression

Answer (score 0):

From ButtonGroup documentation:

> method isSelected(ButtonModel m) - Returns whether a ButtonModel is
> selected.

So to use that method you suppose to pass ButtonModel object there

Comment: if(buttonGroup1.isSelected(ButtonModel m))  i wrote like this way  ') expected   error displayed